# JavaScript: Limit Client to click button twice

Tags: button, cookies, click, ip, client

How can i limit a client to click button only one time per X minutes?

Im not looking for this!

```
function doSomething() {
  document.getElementById("btn").disabled=true;
  setTimeout('document.getElementById("btn").disabled=false;',60000);
  // do stuff here
}
```

NOTE: If user refresh my page he must continue unable to click the button.

I also tried  by getting client IP but i didn't get mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to do this 100% client-side, then you need to set a value in a cookie.

Comment: A smart user could delete his cookies! There is no other way to do it?
Why I can't get his IP?

Comment: Or use local storage (if using a modern browser with that HTML5 capability available) - info at http://w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp  But almost any client side solution is going to involve setting a value the client could manipulate...

Comment: Good call about local storage. Also, if it's *really* that important to thwart the user, then you need to get the server involved, and use some sort of authentication. I assumed this was just to prevent the user from being a pest.

Comment: Excelent!! :O
And user can't reset it?

Comment: Local storage? Sure he/she can.

Comment: User can still re-set local storage.  They are slightly less likely to because people more-so know about cookies, but like @BlakeCaldwell mentioned in comment above, if it is that important, you're going to have to involve some server side authentication.

Comment: OK guys thank you for your help! 
Not so important, i just dont want a user to be a pest like @BlakeCaldwell said!